# jQuery .delay in combination with .fadeOut doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

## The Problem

---

I wanted to add a simple loading animation to my website using jQuery, and it appears when I load the page - but it simply repeats forever and doesn't fade out after 500ms like specified.

## The Code

---

## [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nRBNe/)

### HTML

```
<div class="loading">
    <img src="http://www.puzzlexperts.com/images/Preloader_3.gif" id="loader">
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#loader { 
    display: block; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 45%; 
    top: 45%; 
    z-index: 1000;
}

.loading {
position: absolute; 
    z-index: 100; 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

### JS

```
$(window).load(function() {
        $("#loader").delay(500).fadeOut("slow");
        $(".loading").delay(500).fadeOut("slow");
    }
```

## How it should work

---

I hoped it would show the loading animation on a plain white fullscreen background for 500ms, then fadeOut slowly to reveal the website.

**Do you guys know how to fix this behaviour?**

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with your code plz: http://jsfiddle.net/ ? :)

Comment: Done: http://jsfiddle.net/nRBNe/

Comment: Seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9ksyv/

Comment: What. Mine doesn't work at all. How did you do that?

Comment: @j08691 you're using jQuery 1.11, but I'm using 2.1. Does this not work with jQuery 2.1?

Comment: You're double wrapping your code in window load events.

Comment: Switch my fiddle to 2.x edge and it still works.

Comment: How can I fix the double wrapping?

Comment: Upper left hand corner of jsfiddle look at the load options. Your fiddle has onLoad and you're also adding an onload in your code. Remove one. Oh and BTW, you're missing a closing `)`.

Comment: That solved it. Would you submit an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Actually thanks, but I'll pass. It's more of a jsFiddle typo fix than an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have missed the closing brackets of `window.load`

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#loader").delay(500).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not ended your code properly.

```
$(window).load(function() {
        $("#loader").delay(500).fadeOut("slow");
        $(".loading").delay(500).fadeOut("slow");
    });
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lds2X/1/

Comment: Why are you recommending the use of document.ready over window.load here?

Comment: @j08691. Sorry My mistake. Corrected.